# Save binary as file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, http-post

How Can I save a binary string as a file? I am posting the binary string from Excel.  Here is the code for that:

```
Sub PostFileAsBinary()

Dim Filename  As String
Filename = "\\Network Drive\Test File\TestFile.pdf"
FileURL = "http://localhost:11212/Upload/BinaryFile/"

Dim ReadFile As String
Dim n As Integer
n = FreeFile()

Open Filename For Binary As n
ReadFile = String(LOF(n), vbNullChar)
Get n, , ReadFile
Close n
Debug.Print ReadFile

Set httpReq = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
httpReq.Open "POST", FileURL & "?ID= " & 2, False
httpReq.SetRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(ReadFile)
httpReq.send ReadFile

Debug.Print httpReq.responseText
ReadFile = ""
Set httpReq = Nothing

End Sub
```

Here is my controller action:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostLPFile(int LPKey, string ReadFile)

    {
        using (FileStream srReadFile = new FileStream(@"D:\Temp", FileMode.Create))

        {
            using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(srReadFile))
            {
                writer.Write(ReadFile);

                writer.Close();
            }
        }
        return View();
```

I am successful in posting the binary file, but not able to upload the file at the mentioned location: `\\Network Drive\Posted File`

I think I will have to convert the binary string posted to stream, which I think I am struggling with. Could anyone look into it and help?

Comment: @user793468, have you tried writing it locally? try that first before the UNC address and make sure it is not an issue with IIS pooping out writing to a different domain. (@squillman, my bad)

Comment: @one It's actually not my question, I just cleaned it up a bit.

Comment: @one.beat.consumer I have it locally: FileURL = "http://localhost:11212/Upload/BinaryFile/"

Comment: @user793468, "but not able to upload" is not useful. Please provide details (exception type+message). Also try saving locally (as one suggested), i.e. to temp folder to avoid all permission issues.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I changed it to "D:\Temp" and get the error: Access to the path 'D:\Temp' is denied. I do have access to that folder, why would I get this error?

Comment: d:\temp is not "temporary files" location unless you set permissions properly and changes environmant variables for correct account. Using Path.GetTempFileName would give place with R/W access for current account. See competent_tech answer for explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The security for accessing directory locations in ASP.Net depends on how security is implemented in your web application:

If you are impersonating either the end user or a specific user, then it is that user that will need to have access to the directory location.

If you are not using impersonation, then it is the user identity for the application pool that your web site is running in that will require access to the directory.

**Update**

For more information on what is meant by impersonation in ASP.Net, please see [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Comment: I am not impersonating anyone, I am logged in as myself. Is there a way to impersonate as an admin?

Comment: @user793468: What I meant by impersonation is the user context that requests by ASP.Net are executing as. I updated the answer to include a link to some documentation on MSDN that provides a comprehensive overview of this subject. I think that the easiest approach for you is to modify the IIS application pool user to be a domain user that has access to that network share.

Comment: @user793468, competent_tech is correct... IIS is running your web application as someone, whether it is a built-in account like System, or NetworkService, AppPoolIdentity, or another custom account, none of us know... the issue is whatever account is being used to run your app is the one you are using to write the file. Furthermore, using authentication schemas like WindowsAuth, or Impersonation will cause the access to be done on behalf of the authenticated user's account and thus they would need privileges. Lastly, off-domain file actions are even trickier because they leave the server.

Comment: ...continuing... figure out the permissions thing on your local save first... once that is figured out, then begin looking into using an UNC address for to a file share off-domain

Comment: @one.beat.consumer I resolved the access issue. The next issue I am having is with not being able to save the posted data from "ReadFile" to a variable in my controller action. I know there is a way to assign the posted text to a variable in a controller action, but dont exactly know how

Comment: how is the text coming in? you should be able to grab what comes back from the writer and stuff it in any string value. if the text is HTML MVC could be blocking it on the controller action unless you use the AllowHtml attribute (which you must be careful about sanitizing tags first).